# Not able to import okhttp project in intellij using maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, okhttp

I am not able to successfully import the okhttp project in the intellij.

https://github.com/square/okhttp

I am using intellij community edition: 2016.1
Maven: 3.0

When I hit make. It shows following error message for **"okhttp-tests"** module:

```
Error:(94, 49) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

The language level for all the submodules is automatically set to 5, while for parent it is set to 7.
When I change the language level for okhttp-tests module to 7 and hot make, ideas shown me following error message:

`Error:java: javacTask: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7`

Am i using wrong version of idea/maven ?
Please help.

Also there is no detailed documentation available for importing project/ setting up dev environment on the git repo.
I would like to request okhttp members to create a descriptive Contributors.md file for beginners like me.

Comment: Did your set your environment variable JAVA_HOME to 1.7 or greater?

Comment: yes. Idea picks up the JDK correctly. i.e. JDK1.7.

Answer (score 0):

If JAVA_HOME is set correctly, Please also check the Project Parent POM file for the compiler Version of maven-compiler-plugin

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```